# sorted() getting syntax error on windows system

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Employee():
def __init__(self, name, age, salary):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.salary = salary

def __repr__(self):
    return '({},{},${})'.format(self.name, self.age, self.salary)


from operator import attrgetter

e1 = Employee('Carl', 37, 70000)
e2 = Employee('Kevin', 30, 80000)
e3 = Employee('Rose', 25, 90000)

employees = [e1, e2, e3]

s_employees = sorted[employees, key = attrgetter('age')]

print(s_employees)
```

I am learning through youtube and copied this code to try it myself, but can't replicate the results, I am using windows system and Atom to write the code, the video is watched is using MAC system and sublime does it make it different?

s_employees = sorted[employees, key = attrgetter('age')]
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.141s]

Comment: Function calls use `foo(...)`, not `foo[...]`. Voting to close for simple typographical error.

Comment: Its '(' braces for sorted `sorted(employees, key = attrgetter('age'))`

Comment: wow! thanks i can't believe i made this mistake!

Answer (score 1):

change to `s_employees = sorted(employees, key=attrgetter('age'))`

Answer (score 0):

Before the fancy `attrgetter` syntactic sugar, lets try this:

```
s_employees = sorted(employees, key = lambda employee: employee.age)
```

Next, you can replace the lambda call with:

```
from operator import attrgetter
s_employees = sorted(employees, key = attrgetter('age'))
```

Although, I would also rewrite your `Employee` class to use/inherit `collections.namedtuple`.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Employee = namedtuple("Employee",("name", "age", "salary"))
```